# Cut a string with a known start & end index

Tags: c#, string

When I have a string that I want to cut into a new string from a certain Index to a certain Index, which function do I use?

If the string was:

> ABCDEFG

This would mean retrieving *BCD* when the two indexes specified were *1* and *3*.

Comment: Did you search for this before asking? What did you try so far?

Comment: I don't know why this has downvotes and it's closed, as it's a real question not found in MSDN documentation. He is not looking for startIndex + count, but startIndex + endIndex.

Comment: Not a real question????  Yeah it is!  I found it since I had the same question.  Dear casperOne: WT???

Comment: This is something that C# 8 ranges provides a solution for (https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/12/09/range-type-in-c-8/), about half way down the page under "*A New Substring*"

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If `endIndex` points to the last character that you want to have included in the extracted substring:

```
int length = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
string extracted = s.Substring(startIndex, length);
```

---

If `endIndex` points to the first character following the desired substring (i.e. to the start of the remaining text):

```
int length = endIndex - startIndex;
string extracted = s.Substring(startIndex, length);
```

---

See [String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) for the official description on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/?view=netframework-4.7.1).

---

Since C# 8.0, in .NET Core and .NET 5+ only, you can use [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)

```
string extracted = s[startIndex..endIndex];
```

where the position at endIndex is excluded. This corresponds to my second example with `Substring` where `endIndex` points to the first character following the desired substring (i.e. to the start of the remaining text).

If `endIndex` is intended to point to the last character that you want to have included, just add one to `endIndex`:

```
string extracted = s[startIndex..(endIndex + 1)];
```

Answer (score 6):

This becomes possible with the new [Range feature of C# 8.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/05/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/).

An extension method on `string` that uses `Range` to achieve this is:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SubstringByIndexes(this string value, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        var r = Range.Create(startIndex, endIndex + 1);
        return value[r];
        /*
        // The content of this method can be simplified down to:

        return value[startIndex..endIndex + 1];

        // by using a 'Range Expression' instead of constructing the Range 'long hand'
        */
    }
}
```

*Note: 1 is added to `endIndex` when constructing the Range that's used as the end of the range is exclusive, rather than inclusive.*

Which can be called like this:

```
var someText = "ABCDEFG";

var substring = someText.SubstringByIndexes(1, 3);
```

Giving a value of *BCD* in `substring`.

Comment: Strings can be indexed by `Range` directly. `var substring = someText[1..4]`.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, C# doesn't natively have what you need. C# offers Substring(int startIndex, int length) instead. To achieve Substring(int startIndex, int endIndex), you will need custom implementation. Following extension method can make reusability easier/cleaner:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Substring2(this string value, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        return value.Substring(startIndex, (endIndex - startIndex + 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to substring string..

1 )

```
public string Substring(
    int startIndex
)
```

Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position.

2)

```
public string Substring(
    int startIndex,
    int length
)
```

Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length.

Comment: He wants to provide startIndex and endIndex.  Substring requires start and length.